# How to reconsitute a Date object from a Cloud Function using the Android SDK?

Tags: parse-platform

I have a Cloud Code function that returns a date. It goes across the wire as JSON, as follows:

```
{  
   "result":{  
      "__type":"Date",
      "iso":"2033-07-09T23:50:11.450Z"
   }
}
```

Now, in the Android SDK, I want to reconstitute this JSON string into a Date object. I've tried doing this:

```
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("getSubscriptionExpiryDate", params, new FunctionCallback<Date>() {
    @Override
    public void done(Date date, ParseException e) {...}
});
```

...but I get a ClassCastException.

If I do FunctionCallback< JSONObject>, or FunctionCallback< Date> I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject
       at com.app.helper.ParseConnectionHelper$1.done(ParseConnectionHelper.java:70)
       at com.parse.FunctionCallback.internalDone(FunctionCallback.java:44)
```

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: The SDK does this for you, converting things like arrays and dates to native objects.

Comment: That's what I thought, but haven't been able to make it work. See example of what's been tried in my edit.

Comment: I wish I could be more instructive, but I can't speak the java.  I think the response you're getting back is better declared as a HashMap, but I'm unsure about syntax.  Another idea: in the cloud, don't call `response.success({ result: someDate });`, instead just `response.success(someDate)' and your original code will work (I think).`